# Service and background music codes -updated-

Tags: android, service, background-music

i am making a quiz game that has a background music.i saw a very helpful source code using service and background music here http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html  but my problem is i want to add another sound on my EasyOne.class in my correct answer button. what will i add or edit to  make it work. my point is. everytime i click the a button of my easyone.class it will play a sound and if i  want to turn off all my  music even the corrrect button and the background music it will turn off if ill go to my settings.class and  click the OFF button. hope you can help me.really appriciate it.

here is my code for my service

```
public class MusicService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "";
MediaPlayer player;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bsound);
    player.setLooping(false);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    player.stop();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    player.start();
}
```

}

and here is my for my settings

```
public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  private static final String TAG = "";
  Button on, off, back;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_backk);
    on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_on);
    off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_off);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override   
       public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Back",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
 });    
    on.setOnClickListener(this);
    off.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  public void onClick(View src) {
    switch (src.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_on:
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting srvice");
      startService(new Intent(this, MusicService.class));
      break;
    case R.id.btn_off:
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
      stopService(new Intent(this, MusicService.class));
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

my EasyOne.class - (class of my level 1 easy mode)

```
public class EasyOne extends Activity {

ImageButton a, b, c;
Intent intent ;
CountDownTimer cdt;
TextView timer;
MediaPlayer clap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.easyone);
    a = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_a);
    b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_b);
    c = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_c);
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_timer);
    cdt = new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               timer.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
              timer.setText("TIMES UP!");
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TimesUp.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    };

    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChoiceTwo.class);
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
          //i want to add a sound here that will play if they click this button and can turn it OFF on the setting.class OFF button
            cdt.cancel();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChoiceTwo.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });


    cdt.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main activity of your code (where the game actually starts), put:

```
startService(new Intent(MusicService.class))
```

This will start your music playing as soon as the game starts

Comment: Sure - in the onStart method in EasyOne, simply use the same (or nearly the same) audio playing code as in your Service, e.g.
`MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.othersound);
player.setLooping(false);
player.start();`

Comment: ill justcopy and paste that on my easoyone.class?